# Emacs projectile discover .git projects

Tags: emacs

I am redoing my emacs config, and therefore I loose the repositories that were registered in `projectile`.

I have a `~/repo` directory containing many `.git` repositories. Is there a way to tell `projectile` to find all `.git` without me having to reopen them individually ?

Comment: I guess you weren't able to save your old `projectile-bookmarks.eld` file?

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately not.